# Under what circumstances does Elemental's distributed SVD not work?

Tags: linear-algebra, c++, mpi, lapack, svd

I am playing around with [Elemental's](http://libelemental.org/) distributed singular value decomposition and am running into two particular issues.

Building the test at [tests/lapack_like/SVD.cpp](https://github.com/elemental/Elemental/blob/master/tests/lapack_like/SVD.cpp), and running with

```
mpirun -np 4 ./SVD --height 3 --width 3
```

I get

```
SVD residual was unacceptably large
```

for the distributed `Complex<float>` test (but sequential is OK).

Additionally, when I run with `--height 50 --width 52`, I run into some problem

```
H and A must have the same height
```

The Elemental documentation for SVD is outdated, and I don't know what requirements there are on the dimensions of a matrix in order to take its SVD.

I have Elemental built with pulled OpenBLAS, Scalapack, Metis and Parmetis. I could not manage to get libFLAME linked, even using the reference BLAS/LAPACK implementations.

Comment: I think that question is too specific to Elemental. Maybe you should ask it in the mailing list: **users@libelemental.org**.

Comment: Yeah, I should probably do that too. I was thinking that it might be some algorithmic detail that puts specific requirements on the dimensions/values on an allowable matrix, which I would have look outside of the documentation for.